# $P\left(2X^{2}+2Y^{2}>5XY\right)$, $X,Y \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability

Consider $$f_{X}\left(x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}},x\geq0$$
$$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^{2}}{2}},y\geq0$$
I wish to find $P\left(2X^{2}+2Y^{2}>5XY\right)$. What I did was:
$$P\left(2X^{2}+2Y^{2}>5XY\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\iint_{2X^{2}+2Y^{2}>5XY}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}dxdy$$
but:
$$2X^{2}+2Y^{2}>5XY\implies2r^{2}>5r^{2}\cos\theta\sin\theta\implies\frac{4}{5}>\sin2\theta\implies\theta<\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)$$ then:
$$P\left(2X^{2}+2Y^{2}>5XY\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\iint_{\theta<\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^{2}}rdrd\theta=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)}d\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}k}dk\approx0.295$$

But that doesn't seem to be the correct answer. I couldn't spot my mistake, so I will be glad if anyone can spot it.

Comment: May it also be that the constant before the gaussian is the square root of 1/(2п) instead of 2/п ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that,

$2x^{2}+2y^{2}\geq5xy \implies 2x^{2}+2y^{2}-5xy \geq 0$

$(x-2y)(2x-y) \geq 0; x, y \geq 0$

So we have,

$x \geq 2y \ \cup x \leq \frac{y}{2}$

If you are converting it into polar coordinates,

$ 0 \leq \theta \leq \arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\arctan\left(2\right) \leq \theta \leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$0 \leq r \leq \infty$

Alternatively you could evaluate first for,

$\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right) \leq \theta \leq \arctan(2)$ and then subtract from $1$.

Or simply look at it as,

$ \displaystyle 1 - \dfrac{2}{\pi} \left[\arctan(2) - \arctan(\dfrac{1}{2})\right] \approx 0.59$

Comment: this also allows to compute the probability as a simple angle ratio! (no nasty integrals needed) This is true more generally for  an arbitrary probability distribution with circular symmetry (not necessarily Gaussian)

Comment: @LucaGhidelli that is correct. I added that too.

Comment: Thank you! But what's the false logical step I did in $x^2+y^2 \to r^2$ and $x\to r\cos \theta$, $y\to r\sin \theta$?

Comment: You get $\sin (2\theta) \leq \dfrac{4}{5}$. That gives you one bound. But you also have a bound when $2\theta \geq  \pi - \arcsin (\dfrac{4}{5})$

Comment: @Darkenin please see my revised comment. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in the step $$\frac{4}{5} > \sin 2\theta \implies \theta < \frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5}\ .$$
In general the solution to an inequality of the form $\sin x < y$ should be $(2 k + 1)\pi - \sin^{-1} y < x < 2k\pi + \sin^{-1} y$ for all integers $k$. Thus the possible values of $\theta$ is actually a larger range, including $(0, \frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5})$ as you found, but also $(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\frac{4}{5}, \frac{\pi}{2})$. This means that the right answer should be double the value you obtained.